# Change the symbology of a dynamic map service in client

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to use someone else's map service in my web map, but their symbology is atrocious so I need to render new colors through JavaScript API.

I try the following (amongst many other efforts spanning 2 days):

```
       parcels = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(config.mapServices.parcels, {id:"Parcels"});
       parcels.on("load", function(){

           var layerDrawingOptions = [];
           var layerDrawingOption = new LayerDrawingOptions();

            // set symbology overrides
            layerDrawingOption.renderer = new SimpleRenderer(symbols.polygon);

            // the following index represents the layers in the service to apply the renderer to
            layerDrawingOptions[8] = layerDrawingOption;

            parcels.setLayerDrawingOptions(layerDrawingOptions);
            parcels.setImageFormat("png32");
            parcels.setVisibleLayers([8]); //schools,streets,parks,parcels,boundaries,shields

       })   ;       

        map.addLayer(parcels);
```

I am following this currently:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/layerdrawingoptions-amd.html#renderer

The few examples at the API deal with renderers for class-breaks, etc, I need to resymbolize all parcels, which should be a similar concept. Any ideas on how I can symbolize a dynamic layer at the client rather than the server using JS API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the two most common gotchas for Dynamic Layers are:

1. the service itself doesn't support requests to alter symbology.  (make sure *Supports Dynamic Layers* is `true` in the service [metadata](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer))
2. the index position in the layer drawing options array doesn't match the index position of the layer.

   ```
   var sfs = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
     new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
     new esri.Color([0,255,0]), 2),new esri.Color([0,0,255,1])
   );

   app.renderer = new esri.renderer.SimpleRenderer(sfs);
   var optionsArray = [];
   var drawingOptions = new esri.layers.LayerDrawingOptions();
   drawingOptions.renderer = app.renderer;
   //since we're attempting to alter the drawing rule for layer 3, we insert into the same position
   optionsArray[3] = drawingOptions;
   app.usaLayer.setLayerDrawingOptions(optionsArray);
   ```

i published a working sample [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59331579/js/dynamic-layers-simple-renderer.html)

Comment: Thanks for the clarrification, John. He had "supports dynamic layers" set to false... Do you suppose that was the catch?

Comment: absolutely.  youre never going to be able to modify the symbology of a dynamic map service that doesn't have the capability 'turned on'